# ajax and jquery problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

im using joomla,i have problem...
 when i click on tab its working properly,im using ajax on first page,but on 2nd page im using jquery for slidingshow but tab not working on 2nd pages...
when i remove the following code from the 2nd page...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
```

then tab working on 2nd page but then slideshow not working....i dont know ???

Comment: why are some of you SO users so quick to vote down?

Comment: Check your error messages, also make sure that the scripts are loaded into both tabs if they are needed, and that the locations are correct (If the `tab` page is in a folder then you may need to do `../jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js` for example)

Comment: @dany I feel the same as you: there's no reason to vote this down, yes they could provide us with a little more information but this is clearly a problem that can be solved by SO

Answer (score 1):

You are facing problem because of javascript conflict.please check with js is creating problem and just add noCoflict.js in that.It will solve the problem.